# Getting input from String to simulate mouse clicks

Tags: java

So I have a Java program that splits the screen up into an 8x8 grid, from a1 -> h8. The program is to take a 2 letter input, for example if I type a1 then the mouse should click at the location of a1. I have 2 questions

1) I was wondering, do I actually have to do this:

if (input == a1) 
//click location of a1

64 times? Or is there better way?

2) What should I use to actually do the mouse clicks? And is there a way to click a location without actually moving the mouse?

Comment: Record the current mouse position, use `Robot` to move and click, return the mouse to the start position?

Comment: i did't get your first point.

Comment: i mean do i actually have to write out an if statement for each grid location? or is there a better way? sry i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly:

```
The program is to take a 2 letter input,
```

Your program takes a letter and a number as opposed to two letters, you need to be careful how you phrase things like that as it could affect how someone tries to deal with the solution, no biggy though 
:)

Secondly: No idea if this is the best way but you could potentially create an ArrayList of your grid squares names (a1, a2, a3 e.t.c), then when you recieve input from the user iterate over the list until the input matches an entry in the ArrayList, once found either use robot to create the click, or manually fire an onClickEvent to a listener.  If you find no entry on the list matching the user input then return an error citing invalid reference.

Also, to avoid manually entering each grid reference to the array one at a time, try using char ASCII values, and looping to create the list, similar to below:

```
    char c = 97;
    char n = 49;
    String s = Character.toString(c) + Character.toString(n);
    System.out.println(s);

    myArrray.add(s);
```

By successfully looping the above in the right way you will save adding each grid reference one by one.

Answer (score 0):

use `awt.Robot` class to simulate click.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to you Question 1.

You can use `ArrayList` which will store all values from `a1 to h8`.

Then you can write a single if condition to check.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a1");
list.add("a2");
list.add("a3");
list.add("a4");
String input ="a1";     
if(list.contains(input))
    //click location of a1
else
    //else part
```

The other way is using `Array`:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"a1","a2","a3","a4"};
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]!=null && arr[i].equals(input))
        //click location of a1
}
```